# Como valido un Inicio de sesion en .net usando mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

tengo creada la vista y el controllador del login pero no me valida ni me redirige a las tablas, en este caso a la de estudiantes una vez logeado, es más ni me valida si tiene datos o no, muestro el codigo del controllador

```
public class InicioController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Inicio()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Inicio(Inicio model)
        {
            ColegioConnection modeloBD = new ColegioConnection();
            var usuario = modeloBD.Inicio.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Usuario == model.Usuario && x.Contraseña == model.Contraseña);

            if (usuario == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Mensaje = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";
                return View();
            }

            //Se asigna el nombre del usuario que inicia sesión
            Session["NombreUsuario"] = usuario.NombreUsuario;

            return RedirectToAction("../Estudiante/Index");
        }
    }
```

<--ahora el de la vista del controlador: -->

```
@model Modelo.BaseDatos.Inicio

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Estudiantes", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Inicie Sesion</legend>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border: 1px solid red">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Inicio" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

PD2: la pagina web la hice con capas y mvc, por lo tanto estoy trayendo la BD de un biblioteca de clases llamada Modelo.BaseDatos.
espero me puedan entender

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Como bien indica Miguel, si el código no podemos saber qué es lo que está fallando ni las tecnologías que estás usando. Sugiero que tomes el [tour] y también revises [ask] para que tu pregunta obtenga mayor atención. Si bien la pregunta podría tener una respuesta, la única forma de responder al problema puntual que estás teniendo es que [detalles exactamente qué intentaste hasta ahora](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874). De esa forma, las respuestas pueden estar acotadas a tu caso en particular.

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite.

Comment: Joe, tu pregunta ahora es completamente válida, en cuanto pase por las colas de revisión para su reapertura podrás recibir respuestas para solventar tu problema ;)